# Risk counter example

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, examples-counterexamples, stochastic-calculus, density-function

Im looking for a distribution $P$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a meassurable function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}y^2\ \mathrm dP(x,y)=\infty 
$$
and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(y-g(x))^2\ \mathrm dP(x,y)<\infty.
$$

I tried the density $f_P(x,y):= \mathcal{X}_{[1,\infty)^2}(x,y)/(x^2y^2)$ to fulfill the first equality, but I haven`t found a function $g$ yet to fulfill the second inequality

Comment: Consider the kernel $P(x,dy)=\delta_x(dy)$ and $\mu$ any distribution without finite square moment (the Cauchy distribution entered at $0$  for example) The the distribution $\mu P(dx)$ defined as $\mu P \phi=\int_{\mathbb{R}}P\phi(x)\,\mu(dx)=\int_\mathbb{R}\Big(\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x,y)\delta_x(dy)\big)\,\mu(dy)=\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x,x)\,\mu(dx)$ is such a distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer